# Why Groovy's map does not have metaClass?

Tags: groovy, metaclass

Why does Groovy's literal map does not have a metaClass?

```
// lists work as expected:
aList = []
println aList.class // class java.util.ArrayList
println aList.metaClass  // gives the full blown metaclass
          //     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@3de6696c
          //     [groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@3de6696c[class java.util.ArrayList]]

// string and numbers too:
println ''.metaClass
println 12.metaClass

// map does not:
aMap = [:]
println myMap.metaClass // gives null
println myMap.class // also gives null
```

Tested with:

```
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_31 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use:

```
[:].getMetaClass()
```

The same as if you want to get the `class` of a `Map`, ie:

```
[:].getClass()
```

this is because Maps return the value represented by the given key when you do a property lookup on them.  Otherwise you couldn't have keys `class` or `metaClass`

Comment: On a related topic, is there a way to use missingProperty for a class that implements map ? Ok, I'll post another question...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042449/how-to-use-propertymissing-on-a-class-that-implements-java-util-map-in-groovy