# How to use propertyMissing on a class that implements java.util.Map in groovy

Tags: groovy

I understand that [we cannot access Map properties the same way we access them in other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061053/why-groovys-map-does-not-have-metaclass), because of the ability to get map keys with dot notations in groovy.

Now, Is there a way, for a class that implements java.util.Map, to still benefit from the expando metaclass for using propertyMissing ?

Here is what I'm trying :

```
LinkedHashMap.metaClass.methodMissing = { method, args ->
    println "Invoking ${method}"
    "Invoking ${method}"
}

LinkedHashMap.metaClass.propertyMissing = { method, args ->
    println "Accessing ${method}"
    "Accessing ${method}"
}

def foo = [:]

assert "Invoking bar" == foo.bar() // this works fine
assert "Accessing bar" == foo.bar  // this doesn't work, for obvious reasons, but I'd like to be able to do that...
```

I've been trying through custom DelegatingMetaClasses but didn't succeed...

Comment: Can you give an example where this would be useful? Maybe we can think of a way to do it given an example

Comment: When accessing a key that doesn't exist in the map, I want to try to get another key that I derive from the missing key name...

Comment: For example, for any map, if the key foo_bar is not present, I want to lookup fooBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it fits your use-case, but you could use Guava and the `withDefault` method on Maps...

```
@Grab( 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1' )
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.*

def map
map = [:].withDefault { key -> 
    LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(LOWER_CAMEL, key).with { alternate ->
        map.containsKey(alternate) ? map[alternate] : null
    }
}

map.possibleSolution = 'maybe'

assert map.possible_solution == 'maybe'
```

One side-effect of this is that after the assert, the map contains two key:value pairs:

```
assert map == [possibleSolution:'maybe', possible_solution:'maybe']
```

Comment: Looks like a solution... I'll try that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you can provide a custom map:

```
class CustomMap extends LinkedHashMap {

    def getAt(name) {
        println "getAt($name)"
        def r = super.getAt(name)
        r ? r : this.propertyMissing(name)
    }

    def get(name) {
        println "get($name)"
        super.get(name)
        def r = super.get(name)
        r ? r : this.propertyMissing(name)

    }
    def methodMissing(method, args) {
        println "methodMissing($method, $args)"
        "Invoking ${method}"
    }

    def propertyMissing(method) {
        println "propertyMissing($method)"
        "Accessing ${method}"
    }
}

def foo = [bar:1] as CustomMap

assert foo.bar == 1
assert foo['bar'] ==  1
assert foo.lol == 'Accessing lol'
assert foo['lol'] ==  'Accessing lol'
assert foo.bar() == 'Invoking bar'
```

Comment: Thanks Opal, that would work, but it's not an option. I want this to work on maps returned by an existing API.

Answer (score 0):

I reread the [groovy Maps javadocs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#get(K,%20V)), and I noticed there are 2 versions of the get method. One that takes a single argument, and one that takes 2.

The version that takes 2 does almost what I describe here : it returns a default value if it doesn't find your key.

I get the desired effect, but not in dot notation, therefore I just post this as an alternative solution in case anyone comes across this post :

```
Map.metaClass.customGet = { key ->
    def alternate = key.replaceAll(/_\w/){ it[1].toUpperCase() }
    return delegate.get(key, delegate.get(alternate, 'Sorry...'))
}

def m = [myKey : 'Found your key']

assert 'Found your key' == m.customGet('myKey')

assert 'Found your key' == m.customGet('my_key')

assert 'Sorry...' == m.customGet('another_key')

println m
```

-Result-

> m = [myKey:Found your key, my_key:Found your key, anotherKey:Sorry..., another_key:Sorry...]

As in Tim's solution, this leads to m containing both keys after the second assert + 2 keys with the default value (Sorry...) everytime we ask for a new value not present in the initial map... which could be solved by removing the keys with default values. e.g. :

```
Map.metaClass.customGet = { key ->
    def alternate = key.replaceAll(/_\w/){ it[1].toUpperCase() }
    def ret = delegate.get(key, delegate.get(alternate, 'Sorry...'))
    if (ret == 'Sorry...') {
        delegate.remove(key)
        delegate.remove(alternate)
    }
    ret
}
```

Feel free to comment/correct any mistakes this could lead to... just thinking out loud here...